# Unpublish MVC 4 project from Azure web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-app-service

I created a new web site on Windows Azure and deployed a standard MVC 4 project on there, using the Internet Application template. I think I may have made some mistakes with the NuGet packages trying to solve another problem. I created a new project and published it using the same publishing profile. Now i get this error:

*Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This can happen if the route that services this request (`'{controller}/{action}/{id}'`) does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:
MyCoolWebsite.Controllers.HomeController
NewWebsite.Controllers.HomeController
*

Obviously now the two projects coexist and that's causing problems understandably. How can I dump the old project without deleting and recreating the whole website on Azure? I've searched all around the portal, even in the old version, but haven't found a thing. As far as I see it's not even possible from the management portal to actually see what's installed on the web site.

Comment: Can you FTP to it, and remove what you don't want?

Answer (score 3):

When you publish from Visual Studio you can choose to delete the destination files before publishing. Should help you if you haven't figure this out yet. :)

[image: dialog box]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to manage the content on your Azure Web App other than through publishing, including FTP, Kudu, and various APIs.

The easiest way is probably via Kudu. Go to `https://<yourwebapp>.scm.azurewebsites.net` and open a Debug Console (wither CMD or Powershell will work). You can use commands like `rmdir` from there, or you can just browse the file tree shown in the browser window and click the delete icon on the folder you want to remove.

[image: Kudu Screenshot]